# How to trigger button click and call javascript in asp.net mvc app (cshtml)

Tags: razor

I want to trigger button click and then call javascript code (and jQuery). Button has type **submit** and is inside a modal box. When user clicks 'Submit' I'd like to send some data to my Web API (and close modal box - that's why I use type **submit** for the button). I'm trying to debug it using alerts but I only get the first one (**Test1**). Here is my code:

For button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="add-new-note">Submit</button>
```

For javascript (and jQuery):

```
<script>
    $javascript: alert("Test1");
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $javascript: alert("Test2");
        $("#add-new-note").click(function () {
            $javascript:alert("Test3");
            $.ajax("/notepad/add/",
                {
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        Title: document.getElementById('for-title').innerHTML,
                        Message: document.getElementById('for-message').innerHTML
                    },
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

** Probably I have to use .value instead of .innerHTML but first I have to get to that part of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in here = http://jsfiddle.net/UTwGS/1205/`<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>` i can get all of tests (test1, test2, test3) u need to add jquery liblary.